# How to install FFMPEG in Red Hat OS From source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

Please somebody provide me references for installing FFMPEG with mp3 and h264 codecs enabled from source code.

I gone through official FFMPEG website, No detailed information as how to install FFMPEG with all features enabled and no information about dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [link to recent static builds of `ffmpeg` for Linux](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) on the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page. The builds support the `libmp3lame` (MP3 audio) and `libx264` (H.264 video) encoders. This is your easiest option.

Alternatively you could compile. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile FFmpeg on CentOS & RHEL](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos). This will allow you to customize your build.

Comment: LordNeckbeard you really saved my life, thank you, builds worked like a charm.